# Printing entire tree contents of LocalMachine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I'm trying to develop a c# program to print the entire tree of LocalMachine to the console. So far I've just been able to get the subkeys of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, but nothing deeper than that. I'm relatively sure I need to use some kind of recursion here to get all the contents of subkeys and their subkeys, and so on. I'm just not sure how to go about it. Here's what I've got as of now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace PrintLocalMachine
{
    class PrintLocalMachine
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(Registry.LocalMachine.Name);
            string[] subkeynames = Registry.LocalMachine.GetSubKeyNames();            

            foreach (string subkey in subkeynames)
            {
                try
                {
                    RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey);
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(rk.Name);

                    string[] subkeynames2 = rk.GetSubKeyNames();

                    foreach (string s in subkeynames2)
                    {
                        recurse(s, rk);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }
        }

        private static void recurse(string sub, RegistryKey rk)
        {
            RegistryKey rk2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(sub);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(rk2.Name);

            string[] subkeynames3 = rk.GetSubKeyNames();

            foreach(string s2 in subkeynames3){
                recurse(s2, rk2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain how I should go about this? I really just need to be pointed in the right direction, I've just hit a wall with this.

EDIT: I changed a bit and updated the code; the updated code is hanging on HKEY_CURRENT_MACHINE\SAM, just printing it over and over until StackOverflowException

Comment: Why can't you just go into the Registry Editor, click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, go to File, and click Export? `.reg` files are just text files, you could probably take what's in that file and use it instead. Basically, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Should have added a homework tag sorry, this is for a course assignment. I need to do this via a C# program.

Comment: It is a bad idea to catch `Exception e` unless you rethrow.  Catch the specific exception type(s) that get thrown instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. This kind of problem where you have a structure inside a structure can be solved through recursion. What you need to do is write a recursive function i.e. a function that calls itself until a certain condition satisfies. In this case that condition would be that if a Registry Key has at least one child we need to go inside that Registry Key and we will continue to do so until we reach a leaf node i.e. a Registry Key which has no more children.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] subkeynames = Registry.LocalMachine.GetSubKeyNames();
        Console.Out.WriteLine(Registry.LocalMachine.Name);

        foreach (string subkey in subkeynames)
        {
            try
            {
                //this might raise a security exception
                RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey);
                recurse(rk);
                rk.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Couldnt access key : " + subkey + "\n " + e.ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void recurse(RegistryKey rk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rk.Name);
        string[] subkeys = rk.GetSubKeyNames();

        if (null != subkeys && subkeys.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var subkey in subkeys)
            {
                try
                {
                    //this might raise a security exception
                    RegistryKey key = rk.OpenSubKey(subkey);
                    recurse(key);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write("Couldnt access key : " + subkey + "\n " + e.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seemed to help me get it working, but it's only printing out HKEY_CURRENT_MACHINE\System\ subkeys for whatever reason.

Comment: Perhaps it just takes such a long time to print that it hasnt got to any other subkeys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE yet, but shouldnt it be printing the contents of BCD00000000 first?

Comment: Mine does not allow access to BCD apparently. It is caught by the "could not access key:" portion. It then goes on to print SOFTWARE.

Comment: So this is something machine specific I guess. You should mark this as answer if the code works

Answer (score 2):

recurse() is not [recursion](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson16.html) unless it calls itself. 
Move all your code from main to recurse() and call recurse() from main. 
You might also want to close opened subkeys.